# can I repair part fried socket

Tags: interface, socket, sata

[image: HDD board socket partially fried]
As image shows the power socket is fried, is there a method to repair it?
BTW this is only the fried 4 pins is for +12v and the ground, one +12v still ok but don't know if it enough.

Comment: How did it get that way? Even if you "fix" it, what's to say the damage will not immediately repeat?   Questions on the repair of undocumented products are generally off-topic here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton it was connected while some liquid on the socket, shorted between +12v and Gnd

Comment: That's not a "socket" - It's a "card-edge connector"   i.e. it's a circuit board.  The socket is the thing it plugs into.  Which, BTW, is almost certainly fried also.     I'll try to fix almost anything, but I'd throw that thing above away.  Unless it's EXTREMELY valuable and irreplaceable, in which case you could bypass the connector altogether and just solder jumper wires.  However, if indeed it's "EXTREMELY valuable and irreplaceable", you'd be much better off hiring a professional....

Comment: This is a sata power plug. Do you want to repair is for use or data recovery?

Comment: @Jeroen3 data is at most important, but use is still an aim if possible

Comment: Other components connected to that board may also be fried on either side of the edge connector so it could be a large time investment, unreliable after a fix or even impossible to fix. If the data is critical I'd try to get it off the drive and onto another rather than reusing what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: finding a [replacement connector](https://www.newark.com/molex/47018-4001/connector-sata-rcpt-22pos-smt/dp/74M7282). Exact fit might be difficult.
Option 2: replace by using a donor part. Find same model drive and swap part.
Option 3: hotwire power by directly soldering to pcb traces.
Option 4: board swap. (complicated)
Option 5: sending it to professionals.

---

This all assumes **only** the connector [failed](https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/dangerous-molex-to-sata-cables) due to being a [cheap](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/69344-melting-sata-power-cable/) sata power adapters. And no failure in the drive itself.

Comment: I'd go with option 2 and even then if and only if the data was worth the effort

Comment: thanks @jeroen3 I didn't know something like this exist https://shopee.com.my/(the-heart)5Pcs-SATA-7-15-pin-power-data-PCB-SMT-panel-mount-connector-i.161511893.2443565743

Comment: @mhaselup I tried, didn't find

Comment: BTW it wasn't cheap but just haste and stupidity after cleaning the connector without drying it enough

Answer (score 0):

cleaning fried plastic and using striped wire fuse on the plastic by heat solved the problem